# What do I do with a dog who vomits while recovering from surgery?

Tags: dogs, health

My dog's name is Magic (a Pomeranian).  She's about 13 years old now.  She went through emergency surgery for pyometra (a uterine infection) 3 days ago (Wednesday, Jan. 29th, 2014) and ever since then, she hasn't eaten anything.

Just about an hour ago, she threw up greenish fluid and start frothing.

Should I be worried?  What do I do?

Comment: I am not sure what that surgery is for, but this sounds a lot like you need to go straight to your vet.

Comment: Seconded. This requires immediate vet notification.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I did call my vet and she asked me to give her homeopathy which puts Magic to sleep so we're hoping she'll sleep through the night.

Comment: Please try to avoid using the term "put to sleep" when referring to a dog taking nap, for the obvious implications. :-)

Comment: Note that a vet prescribing homeopathic remedies is probably treating the pet owner's stress, not the pet ... pets don't respond to the placebo effect. You may want to challenge this and/or seek a second opinion. (I'm not opposed to all alternative medical treatments,  but homeopathy is placebo by definition)

Answer (score 9):

You should call your vet immediately!

Comment: Like; right now, not in the next morning.

Comment: Hey Magic has started breathing very heavily. I don't know what to do. Please advice

Comment: She has pooped and the last time she threw up was at 2 after drinking lots of water. I tried to give her water now but shes not taking in anything and shes just breathing heavy.

Comment: Please take her to the vet.